# Porque tengo este error en Spring

Tags: spring, java-ee, spring-boot, spring-mvc, glassfish

Soy nuevo en Spring, estoy tratando de hacer el deploy de una app Spring en glassfish pero hasta ahora no he podido porque siempre me sale este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que Catalina es de Tomcat pero no entiendo porque lo nombra, yo quiero utilizar Glassfish, no entiendo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072181/org-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception-when-trying-to-start-glassfish-server-wit

Comment: Antes de hacer el deploy tienes que saber que spring boot se puede correr desde un `.jar` directamente en un terminal con el comando `java -jar miApp.jar` Para configurar el deploy con `.war` necesitar hacer algunas configuraciones en tu `.pom`. Por favor publícalo para ver si es por ahí el error.